# SVN for Webstorm, Eclipse, Jhipster all in one

Tags: eclipse, svn

I'm working on a big project that use Java Hipster to generate a front based on angular and boostrap and a back based on spring.
lately i found a good IDE for javascript (webstrom) that I'd like to use.
but I dont find any plugin for java in this IDE, so i'm trying to use both eclipse and webstorm.
the problem is i'm working with too many people on the project, and we are using SVN.
I dont know how we can use svn for both IDE and synchronize the work of each other especially the merge

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Intellij IDEA: the Web part is the same as Webstorm (this is done by the same company, JetBrains, and is in fact the same product), but you also have a great Java IDE.

That's what I personally use to work on JHipster, and I'm the JHipster project lead :-)

If you want a free alternative, have a look at what we provide with our [JHipster Devbox](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-devbox): it's done so you have the best free/OSS environment out-of-the-box. It is based on Spring Tool Suite (for Java IDE) and Atom (for Web development), and this is what we use for the JHipster trainings, and what most of my clients use.

Concerning SVN, all JHipster is done with Git in mind: you can still probably use it with SVN, but you will have to do the configuration yourself (JHipster generates the Git configuration, not the SVN configuration), and of course the tool is far less powerful than Git.